# Grails/Groovy domain classes inheritance cast

Tags: grails, inheritance, groovy, grails-orm

I have modeled my domain classes in Grails with inheritance as shown below.

```
abstract class Profile{
}

class Team extends Profile{
}

class User extends Profile{
}

class B{
    static hasMany = [profiles: Profile]
}
```

Later in the controllers when I get all profiles from the class B in some situations I'd like to cast some of the profiles to Team or to User, but I can't because I get a java.lang.ClassCastException or GroovyCastException, although they are saved as a Team or User (with the attribute class in the database). Here are the ways I have tried:

```
def team1 = b.profiles.toList()[0] as Team

def team1 = (Team)b.profiles.toList()[0]
```

It is working when I don't write any type just use it as it is normal in a dynamic language.

```
def team1 = b.profiles.toList()[0]
```

But then I never know which class I am using. Is there anyway in groovy or gorm to cast the parent class to child?

Comment: There is no [discriminator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/discriminator.html) for gorm to choose between `User` or `Team`.  How should gorm decide which implementation to use?

Comment: It saves to the same table in the database with a class attribute which indicates which class is it.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is **No** as a real GORM/Hibernate instance is a proxied object. So it cannot be cast to an entity class directly.

Anyway this might help:

```
def team1 = b.profiles.toList()[0]
if(team1.instanceOf(Team)) {
    // I am an instance of Team
    // do something here.
}
```

Comment: It is working, but actually that wasn't my question. My question was if there is a way to explicitly cast the base class to subclass.

Comment: No, because the hibernate proxy isn't necessarily an `instanceof` the subclass in the Java sense of the word.  The proxy class is a dynamically generated subclass of the _declared_ type of `b.profiles` (i.e. `Profile`).  [This article](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/) has the gory details, and it (and the others articles in the same series) are well worth a read.

Comment: There's always `GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapIfProxy`, which will remove the proxy wrapper and give you the real object (which you can then cast) but this will have to hit the database if the real object has not already been loaded.